# How do I reference a table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Afternoon,

I wish to pass the row number of a table to a function to reference that specific row in that specific table, for example say I have this:

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr><td>some stuff...</td><tr>
  <tr><td>stuff</td><tr>
  <tr><td>more stuff</td><tr>
  <tr><td>some stuff</td><tr>
  <tr><td>some stuff</td><tr>
</table>
```

and I have looped through the table rows and obtained the index, so in this example say I wanted to do something with the third row (which would have an index of 2, the one which has the contents "more stuff"). And I passed this through a function, like this

```
manipulateRow(2)
```

and this is my whole function

```
function manipulateRow(rowIndex){

/* do something */

}
```

How do you refer the rowIndex parameter to the table within the function? For example:

```
$('#foo').child("tr")[rowIndex].html('<td>i now contain even more stuff!</td>'); // I know this is wrong, how do I make it right?
```

Sorry if I'm being a bit thick or not explaining myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy.

```
$("#foo tr:eq("+rowIndex+")").html("<td>i now contain even more stuff!</td>");
```

Learn more about jQuery selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

that could work actually only like this:

```
$($('#foo tr')[rowIndex]).html('<td>i now contain even more stuff!</td>');
```

but best to use :eq

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#foo > tr').eq(rowIndex).html('<td>i now contain even more stuff!</td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function manipulateRow(rowIndex) {
    var $row = $('#foo tr:nth-child(' + rowIndex + ')');
    ...
}
```

See [nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>footer information</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

$("#myTable > tbody").append("<tr><td>row content</td></tr>");
```

heres another example inline editing:

```
function editRow(row) {
    $('td',row).each(function() {
         $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
    });
}
```